# Can't reload Puppet configuration -> inability to connect to Puppet Server

Tags: ssl, puppet

I'm using two Vagrant VMs to test some things with Puppet, but when I go to request a cert, I get a cryptic error message that I can't find any information about.

I should note that in correspondence with good Linux server administration I'm use `/var/` and `/opt/` for storing sensitive cert info, but otherwise a standard Puppet setup.

```
# Client node details
IP: 192.168.250.10 
Hostname: client.example.com
Puppet version: 4.3.2
OS: CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (on Vagrant)

# Puppet server details
IP: 192.168.250.6
Hostname: puppet-server.example.com
Puppet version: 4.3.2
OS: CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (on Vagrant)

# client's and server's /etc/hosts files are identical
192.168.250.5  puppetmaster.example.com
192.168.250.6  puppet.example.com puppet-server.example.com
192.168.250.7  dashserver.example.com dashboard.example.com
192.168.250.10 client.example.com
192.168.250.20 webserver.example.com

# /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf on both client and server
[main]
    logdest = syslog
[user]
    bucketdir = $clientbucketdir
    vardir = /var/opt/puppetlabs/server
    ssldir = $vardir/ssl
[agent]
    server = puppet.example.com
[master]
    certname = puppet.example.com
    vardir = /var/opt/puppetlabs/puppetserver
    ssldir = $vardir/ssl
    logdir = /var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver
    rundir = /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver
    pidfile = /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver/puppetserver.pid
    trusted_server_facts = true
    reports = store
    cacert = /var/opt/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ssl/certs/ca.pem
    cacrl = /var/opt/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ssl/crl.pem
    hostcert = /var/opt/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ssl/certs/{puppet, client}.example.com.pem  # respectively, obviously
    hostprivkey = /var/opt/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ssl/private_keys/{puppet, client}.example.com.pem # respectively, obviously
```

Finally, the error I get:

```
$ sudo puppet resource service puppet ensure=stopped enable=false
Notice: /Service[puppet]/ensure: ensure changed 'running' to 'stopped'
service { 'puppet':
  ensure => 'stopped',
  enable => 'false',
}
$ sudo puppet resource service puppet ensure=running enable=true
Notice: /Service[puppet]/ensure: ensure changed 'stopped' to 'running'
service { 'puppet':
  ensure => 'running',
  enable => 'true',
}
$ puppet agent --test --server=puppet.example.com
Error: Could not request certificate: Permission denied @ dir_initialize - /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys
Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled
```

First of all, with this setup Puppet should not be using `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys`. It's not using my configuration file correctly:

```
$ puppet config print ssldir 
/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl
```

Next, I went through and regenerated the keys on BOTH the server and the client nodes [as prescribed in the Puppet docs](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.3/reference/ssl_regenerate_certificates.html), however I still got the same error and both the client AND server still think my `$ssldir` is `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl` when it should be `/var/opt/puppetlabs/puppetserver/ssl`.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the output from `puppet config print ssldir` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the ssl and vardir config in the agent section as well as master.

[the user section is only applicable to the puppet apply commands etc](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/config_file_main.html)

Comment: Just the `[main]` section should do too. This is assuming he's testing with the master and the agent on the same machine. It was not clear from the question. If they're not, this needs to be configured on the agent machine before puppet agent is run.

Comment: it's on two different vagrant VM machines, one for puppet agent, another for Puppet Server. Which nodes need vardir and ssldir (and in which sections)?

Comment: The agent needs them in the vardir section and the server needs them in the master section. Or you could just add it to the main section of both